# Take Access DB from PC to Web Version

Tags: php, mysql, html, ms-access, ms-office

Project: Turn an Access DB into a Web Based application.

Access DB Desc: There are two .mdbs associated. One holds nothing but forms for interacting with a bac kend .mdb. For every client there is an mdb file with their companies specific information which I refer to as the backend. The client loads up access, then chooses their company specific back end and interacts with it through front end forms generating reports, modifying back end data and so on.

Progress: I've created the majority of the forms duplicating the access front end using php and HTML. I'm in the process of building the table in a MySQL DB replicating the back end access DB.

Question: Is there a tool out there that does this process? that takes a DB front end and back end and automates the process of becoming web based? Is there a version of Access for the Cloud that can be password protected?

I've looked at products like Zoho and a few others, they don't seem to replicate forms, only tables which does me no good.

Any help or input is appreciated.

Comment: *"takes a DB front end and back end and automates the process of becoming web based"* - You mean actually creating the code automatically?  I wouldn't imagine so.  And even if there's a tool which _claims_ to do this, it would undoubtedly create _terrible_ code.  Going from MS Access to PHP/MySQL you're crossing a lot of paradigm boundaries.  Better to re-implement it properly than to try to directly port code from one set of paradigms into another set of paradigms.  (In short... Write the application the PHP way.  Don't write it the Access way with PHP code.)

Comment: That's what I figured, it's quite a bit of data and coding.

Comment: *"I've created the majority of the forms duplicating the access front end using php and HTML. "* - Aren't you pretty much almost done, then?  There may be some business logic to implement outside of the forms, sure.  But at this point you pretty much just need to access the database, right?  You could stick with MS Access and use that from the PHP code.  Or once you transfer the MS Access data into MySQL use that database instead.  What's left to be done?

Comment: Re-implementing something on an entirely new platform usually is quite a bit of coding.  There's a silver lining here, though.  This is an opportunity to really define, capture, and understand the different logical tiers and components of the application.  By keeping concerns within the application properly separated in this new implementation, re-implementing in the future would become significantly easier.  (Swapping out the database, for example, becomes almost trivial if the data access code is properly encapsulated.)

Comment: It is possible to run MS Access 2010 on-line with Sharepoint, it is designed for it, but I do not think that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the input. @David: Once you have the front end forms and the backend DB, there's tons of SQL calls to get the data and tons of JS or AJAX or whatever to manipulate data on the client side. The latter half is more difficult than the first half IMO.

Comment: @Brant: I guess I would have included the JS/AJAX with "the forms" since it's UI work.  As for the SQL calls, that all depends on how you design it.  You could potentially use an out-of-the-box ORM for the direct data access.  Designing some simple repositories is another option for data access, depending on how your models are organized and how simple or complex they are.  This is more related to the latter comment about using this as an opportunity to design this in a highly de-coupled manner to make such development easier.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in Access 2010  you now have a web publishing option. Your forms you create in Access get conveted into .net XMAL (zammel) forms. In fact the work rather nice as they are full AJAX forms and sub forems etc. even dynamic load to save bandwith.

Any code you write in a access web form becomes JavaScrip and runs local in the browser. (you have to write this code using the new editor – VBA does not run inn these forms).

You can publish the web site to office 365 which is dirt cheap (starts at $6 per month). Here is an example of such an access application running and note how in the half way point I switch to running the application 100% in a browser.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AU4mH0jPntI

Also keep in mind these resulting forms are based on web standards and no ActiveX or Silverlight is required on the client side (so the forms work on an iPad for example).

And because you back end is not in a accDB file, but residing on tables (lists) in office 365, then you using a very large and very horizontal scalable server farm (no real limits on the number of users).

In additional to publishing your web application to office 365, you can also publish to SharePoint 2010 (but you need the enterprise edition on site). You can also choose someone like www.accesshosting.com

While this setup gives you a great RAD and quick way to develop a web application with Access do keep in mind there is no conversion utility for existing forms or VBA code.

However, you can convert an existing VBA application to web based and continue to use the VBA application on each user's desktop with the back end data in the cloud. Then over time you can add a few web forms to the SAME application for things like tablets etc. This is known has a hybrid application. (both web parts and legacy VBA parts exist in the same application).

So depending on your needs, one great way to get Access up in the cloud is in fact to use Access.

Comment: Oh wow... THAT. SOUNDS. WICKED GREAT!! Thanks sooooo much!!! Man, youmay have just saved my life!

Answer (score 1):

Front-end? No. Back-End?: [MySql Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/) has data migration tools specifically designed for copying the shcema from multiple sources, including Access. I've used it many times and been happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a VBA Macro inside a module to "export" basic forms to html. To use it add a module in database and replace in first for loop the form name to your form name. It's really basic script, but you can increment it. Actually only exports texts controls.

```
Public Sub main()
  On Error Resume Next
  Dim ctl As Control
  Dim ppt As Property

  For Each ctl In Form_frmDadosGerais.Controls
    i_hType = ""
    i_name = ""
    i_cSource = ""
    'Debug.Print ctl.name & "  " & ctl.Properties.Count
    i_name = ctl.name
    For Each ppt In ctl.Properties
      If ppt.name = "Caption" Or ppt.name = "Visible" Then
        'REM Debug.Print "   " & ppt.Name & ":" & ppt.Value

      ElseIf ppt.name = "Width" Or ppt.name = "Height" Or ppt.name = "Top" Or ppt.name = "Left" Then
        'REM Debug.Print "   " & ppt.Name & ":" & getPixelsFrom(ppt.Value)

      ElseIf ppt.name = "ControlType" Then
        'REM Debug.Print "   " & ppt.Name & ":" & getCotrolType(ppt.Value)
        i_hType = getCotrolType(ppt.Value)

      ElseIf ppt.name = "ControlSource" Then
        i_cSource = ppt.Value

      ElseIf ppt.name = "Name" Or ppt.name = "ControlType" Or ppt.name = "ControlSource" Or ppt.name = "Format" Or ppt.name = "DecimalPlaces" Or ppt.name = "TextFormat" Then
        'REM Debug.Print "   " & ppt.Name & ":" & ppt.Value

      Else
        'REM Debug.Print ppt.Name

      End If

    Next ppt

    If i_hType = "text" Then
      Debug.Print getControlAsMaterialHtml(i_hType, i_name, i_cSource, "Tool Tip Text")
    End If
  Next ctl
End Sub


Public Function getCotrolType(ByRef ControlType As Variant) As String
    If ControlType = 109 Then
        getCotrolType = "text"
    ElseIf ControlType = 100 Then
        getCotrolType = "label"
    Else
        getCotrolType = "unknow (" & ControlType & ")"
    End If
End Function


Public Function getPixelsFrom(ByVal v As Variant) As String
  getPixelsFrom = Round(v / 2.54) & "px"
End Function


Public Function getControlAsMaterialHtml(hType As Variant, name As Variant, controlSource As Variant, ttip As Variant) As String
  h = "<div class=""form-group form-md-line-input"">" & Chr(10)
  h = h & "   <input type=""" & hType & """ class=""form-control"" name=""" & name & """ id=""" & name & """ [(ngModel)]=""model." & controlSource & """ placeholder=""Enter your email"">" & Chr(10)
  h = h & "   <label for=""" & name & """>" & name & "</label>" & Chr(10)
  h = h & "   <span class=""help-block"">" & ttip & "</span>" & Chr(10)
  h = h & "</div>" & Chr(10) & Chr(10)

  getControlAsMaterialHtml = h
End Function
```

Remember it's needs improvements, but you can start from here.

To tables and data, if you are using linux, you can use mdb-tools, using it you can export tables and data directly to MySql server.

Good luck!